# XMLHttpRequest.onload constructor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, constructor

When making a new XMLHttpRequest, like so

```
let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

There is a method (property ?) called onload. My question is, why we can assign a function to it? like this

```
http.onload = function(){};
```

If onload is a property in XMLHttpRequest, the value of it will change when we assign a new value to it, like a function, right?

What is the XMLHttpRequest.onload constructor looks like?
I am really confused about this.

Comment: You can assign a function to *any* property of *any* object.

Comment: Why you dont use fetch? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: Unsure what you're asking so here are a few pointers.When you assign a function to that property, the system will call that function for you.  Are you asking how can you register multiple handlers? Because you also do it by using `http.addEventHandler('load',()=>{})`

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I am curious what is the property in the object looks like, that let us assign our own function to it. The onload property in XMLHttpRequest must be exist, right?

Comment: Yes, in JavaScript you can set any property to anything as Pointy has said. All properties are dynamic. That property is initially unset, you can set it and someone else can override it, so that your original function won't be called.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest onLoad is just an event. From what I understand by your question what you need to know is that there's no actual variable/function assign to it by default. Events are simply "empty" placeholders so that you can assign Event Handlers to them (functions that execute a task when such event is triggered).

Comment: By the way, that's not a particularly important event for the XMLHttpRequest object that you should concern yourself too much with. Look into the response events for AJAX requests, that's when it gets interesting.

Comment: Ok, so here event is completely different from property, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we first started writing HTML event handlers, we would write

```
<button onclick="alert('Hey you')"> Say Hi</button>
```

When you translate the HTML into the DOM, you get a reference to an object and you can also set that event handler by setting a property to a function. The browser will call that function for you when the user clicks the button. **This is a poor man's event system using properties as callbacks**.

Those were the two ways to set an event handler:

- XML attribute
- DOM element reference by setting a property

After a while, they realized that multiple listeners may need to be set (overwriting a property would override the previous listener). We created hacks to allow setting multiple handlers by creating function that called other functions and there was a need for a real event system. The DOM element became an [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), and you can now use a more common Event interface.

```
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('second handler'));
```

So we have three different ways of setting events. `XmlHttpRequest` also implements its own [XMLHttpRequestEventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget) event target, so you can set "events" in both ways, through callback properties and `addEventListener`.

---

In your question, you said: "What is the XMLHttpRequest.onload constructor looks like?" You probably meant how can we override the onload property because a property doesn't have a constructor, its value has a constructor, but we typically assign it using a literal. It's initially unset (`undefined`), if it's never set, it won't get called.

Answer (score 0):

It uses XMLHttpRequest() in its program;
Everything works on the ChromeDev per-browser. However, when I try to run the page in other browsers this method is blocked.

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfE0k.png

In the MDN documentation it is written that currently the method is supported by all browsers.
Does anyone know why I can't run my script in other browsers?

```js
function loadDocumentCsv() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function () {
    const request = this.responseText.toString();
    const allRecords = downloadElement("#allRecords");
    const isofixTrue = downloadElement("#isofixTrue");
    const brandSort = downloadElement("#brandSort");
    const sortMileageAndIsofixFalse = downloadElement("#sortMileageAndIsofixFalse");

    allRecords.innerHTML = "";
    isofixTrue.innerHTML = "";
    brandSort.innerHTML = "";
    sortMileageAndIsofixFalse.innerHTML = '';

    const arrayData = request.replace(/\n/g, ",").split(",");

    const newArray = arrayData.map((element, index) => {
      element.trim();
      if (index > 4) {
        if (index % 5 === 2) {
          const cutLetters = element.replace(/[^0-9]+/, "");
          element = Number(cutLetters.substring(cutLetters.length - 4, cutLetters.length));
          if (element == 0) element = 2007;
        } else if (index % 5 === 3) {
          element = Number(element.replace(/[^0-9]+/, ""));
        } else if (index % 5 === 4) {
          element = element.trim() === "TRUE";
        }
      }
      return element;
    });

    const arrayOfArrays = [];
    while (newArray.length) {
      const addArrayToArrays = newArray.splice(0, 5);
      arrayOfArrays.push(addArrayToArrays);
    }

    //header table
    const header = arrayOfArrays.splice(0, 1);
    const firstRow = (table) =>
      header.forEach((el) => {
        const item = templateHtml(el, "font-weight-bold");
        table.appendChild(item);
    });
    
    //ALL CARS
    firstRow(allRecords);
        arrayOfArrays.forEach((element, index) => {
          const item = templateHtml(element);
          allRecords.appendChild(item);

          const item2 = templateHtml(element);
          element[4] === true || index === 0 ? isofixTrue.appendChild(item2) : "";
        });

    //isofix == TRUE
    firstRow(isofixTrue);

    //sort Brand
    firstRow(brandSort);
    arrayOfArrays.sort(sortedBrand);
    arrayOfArrays.forEach((element) => {
      const item = templateHtml(element, "font-weight-normal");
      brandSort.appendChild(item);
    });

    // sortMileageAndIsofixFalse
    firstRow(sortMileageAndIsofixFalse);
    arrayOfArrays.sort((prev, next) => prev[3]- next[3]);
    arrayOfArrays.forEach((element) => {
      const item = templateHtml(element, "font-weight-normal");
      element[4] === false ? sortMileageAndIsofixFalse.appendChild(item) : "";
    });
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "Cars.csv");
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/solid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body id="body">
    <section class="container loadClick mb-5">
                <button type="button" onclick="loadDocumentCsv()" class="btn loadDocument font-weight-bold">Wyświetl wszystkie tabele</button>
    </section>

    <section class="container">
        <h2>1. Wszystkie samochody</h2>
        <div id="allRecords"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="container mt-5">
        <h2>2. Samochody gdzie Isofix === TRUE</h2>
        <div id="isofixTrue"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="container mt-5">
        <h2>3. Posortowane samochody wg Marki</h2>
        <div id="brandSort"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="container mt-5">
        <h2>4. Samochody gdzie Isofix === FALSE, posortowane wg przebiegu od najmniejszego do największego</h2>
        <div id="sortMileageAndIsofixFalse"></div>
    </section>
    
    <div id="fixed">
        <a href="#body"><i class="uis uis-arrow-circle-up"></i></a>
    </div>
    
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSV file looks like this:
Brand,Model,Year of production,Mileage,Isofix
Alfa Romeo,156,1998,600 000,TRUE
Chrysler,Voyager,2007,342 121,FALSE
Smart,Cabrio,2005,422122,TRUE
Fiat,500,2001 unkown,121333,FALSE
Chrysler,Voyager,2005,421 325,FALSE
Smart,Liftback,2015,534531,TRUE